# Android: Add a view to a specific Layout from code

Tags: android, layout

I want to dynamically add some views to a `LinearLayout` that is already defined in XML.

I'm able to add views to the screen but they are not being placed 'inside' the right `LinearLayout`.

How can I get a reference to this specific Layout from code, similar to getting a `View` by using `findViewById()`?

Comment: If you end up with your views not in the right LinearLayout, it means you have a bad reference to it. Try checking if you find your linear layout by id in the correct way (aka by it's unique ID defined in the XML file). And without code, not much can be said.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As Marcarse pointed out you can do

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("Added tv");
layout.addView(tv);
```

The LinearLayout class extends [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) which itself extends the View class. This makes acquiring a reference to a layout as easy as getting a reference to another View.

Comment: Works for me, thanks! Only a note, in my case I was using horizontal orientation, but every time that I added the new item, it didn't appear. Only when I changed the orientation to vertical the new item appeared.

Answer (score 22):

This should work:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("Added tv");
layout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: every time i reload the activity, the newly added views does not appear. I want to know that how to make those views to a `ViewGroup` so that they are added permanently? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Better Version: 
To add another layout in activity/Fragment

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View mProgressBarFooter = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null, false);
textLoader = (TextView) mProgressBarFooter.findViewById(R.id.footer_label);
```

Happy Coding(-:

Comment: How does the answer relate to the question?

Comment: This is what i was looking for.