# How to add a view to another in android?

Tags: android, view, addition, android-view

Is there any way to add a view to another at specified place? i.e I want to add a child view at (x, y) location of parent view. Please help me.

```
  parentView.addView(childView);
```

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477581/android-add-a-view-to-a-specific-layout-from-code

Comment: @Zakaria I don't think it's a duplicate.  The OP's issue is not adding the view to a parent, but placing it at a pre-defined position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the `LayoutParams` in a `RelativeLayaout`

An example:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = 50; //Your X coordinate
params.topMargin = 60; //Your Y coordinate
parentView.addView(childView,params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a view at (x,y) location of the parent.  However you can trick it to achieve something like this:

1. Have your parent be `RelativeLayout`
2. Define your child view with `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true", android:layout_alignParentTop="true", android:layout_marginLeft="X" android:layout_marginTop="Y"` (or define the same things via code using `LayoutParams`)
3. Add your child to your parent: `parentView.addView(childView)`