# How to make a Button that creates another button in a diffrent class/activity/xml?

Tags: android, eclipse, class, button, android-activity

I was wondering how I can program a button in my android application to create/make a new button in a different xml/class?
Can someone help me with this?
Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two approches to this.

1. Create the button you want to be enabled but the other button in your XML layout file as usual. Then set it's `android:visibility` parameter to `gone` or `invisible`. Now you can control wether or not the view will be visible or not from code. User `View.setVisibility()` to change that.
   Check this link for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int) (it also explains the difference between `invisible` and `gone`)
2. You can add a view to a `ViewGroup` dynamically from code. In order to do that you can create the button you want from code - `... new Button(...)...` and then adding it to your desired `ViewGroup` by calling `ViewGroup.addView(...)`.
   More on that topic: [Android: Add a view to a specific Layout from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477581/android-add-a-view-to-a-specific-layout-from-code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setVisibility method.

Simply set it to INVISIBLE for the button that you wish to "create" and when the user clicks the first button, set the setVisibility to VISIBLE for the second button, and it'll seem like you made a new button.

read more at:
[public void setVisibility (int visibility)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)